# What is the cost personally of my Trip?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, uk-residents

What is the cost personally of my Trip please

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: You keep asking virtually the same question. It’s impossible for anyone on TSE to tell you what to enter to suit your income and finances, that’s something you have to decide. But in line with a previous answer, I’d say the ECO thinks you can’t afford the trip, end of. Which means it doesn’t matter what you write, you are highly unlikely to get a visa at the moment. Wait a while and save more in the meantime.

Comment: Upon looking at the numbers, it appears you make about £400 a month which is not bad for a developing country.. I am originally from a developing country and it is very normal for people to spend a disproportionate part of their income on a foreign travel because foreign travel is viewed as prestigious. The €1000 you said you would spend for one week in UK was too much. When I visit my friends in London, I spend less than £300 a week unless I am living in a hotel.

Comment: When or if you apply next time, make sure you use good numbers. Although I agree with Traveler that the ECO thinks you can’t afford the trip, I think the numbers you used also gave him the opportunity to refuse you based on that calculation.

Comment: @Thameur Are you applying online? The questions you’ve posted look different - as I recall the online form does not include questions breaking down the cost of the trip in detail, such as 70, and 73-75 in your post.

Comment: yes I applied online - and the questions are the same and I would like to understand I am not an Englishman to interpret these questions

Comment: You are using the old form. The newer one is much simpler.

Comment: @Hanky Panky this form for Algiers country !!!

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Applying again claiming a lower expenditure is a bad plan unless that expenditure is justified. The visa was refused because the ECO didn't believe the asker was a genuine visitor: it is felt that a genuine visitor wouldn't be prepared to spend more than their annual living expenses on a one-week holiday. Applying again doesn't alter the fact that the asker appeared not to be a genuine visitor the first time.

Comment: What is the visa refusal rate for people from developing economies? Have you ever applied for a visa as a person from a developing economy?

Comment: @MusoniusRufus You be 'nice' please. I edited your comments with those of someone else, to get some nastiness of the site.